Divide world into four different and equal quadrants
I'm beginning to use and explore NetLogo. For one of my study codes I would like to divide my world in 4 different, but equal, quadrants - just like the Cartesian coordinate system - using patches coordinates.
The furthest I got, reading other questions here, was to divide the world in two parts, as that:
ask patches [
   ifelse (pycor > 0)
    [set quadrant 1]
    [set quadrant 2]

And something in that way, I think, should be what I need.

I think the most appropiate way to approach this would be using an ifelse comand like so:
ask patches [
  (ifelse
    (pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0)[set quadrant 1]
    (pxcor < 0 and pycor > 0)[set quadrant 2]
    (pxcor < 0 and pycor < 0)[set quadrant 3]
    (pxcor > 0 and pycor < 0)[set quadrant 4]
  )
]

However, you this won't set the quadrant variable for patches with one of their coordinates equal to zero, you have to decide in which one you want to include them and modify the code (with <= and >=) accordingly. Also, remember to make sure you declare quadrant as a patch variable!
